# Как передать список ссылок для парсинга в curl

Tags: php, массивы, curl, get, file-get-contents

Мне необходимо, чтобы сайты для парсинга брались с файла .txt, но я не знаю можно ли это реализовать, а главное как правильно.

Что я нашёл:
Вариантов несколько: Если страницу надо получить с удаленного сервера:`введите

```html
$handle = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.example.com/");
    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $homepage = curl_exec($handle);
    curl_close($handle);
echo $homepage;
```

Но,как видно выше в примере за основу берется только 1 конкретный сайт, а у меня же список урлов в .txt.
Я думал найти, что-то типа:

```html
   $url = 'file.txt';
$curlCh = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curlCh, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
```

Answer (score 1):

Сперва оборачиваете код CURL в пользовательскую функцию, потом читаете текст.файл в массив, а потом проходите по этому массиву циклом, передавая в функцию-обёртку значения на каждой итерации. Ну и распечатываете полученный массив удобным для вас способом. Например:

```
// Массив ссылок, полученный из текст.файла
$links = ['http://www.example.com', 'http://www.spravkaweb.ru/mysql/sql'];
$content = [];

foreach ($links as $link) {
    $content[] = get_data($link);
}

echo '<pre>', print_r($content, true), '</pre>';


function get_data($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    $homepage = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $homepage;
}
```

Comment: Здравствуйте!Спасибо,большое,что ответили на мой вопрос,однако так как я новичок быдло кодер не все смог понять.Но у меня главная проблема это занести всё что в txt в массив,а потом грамотно обработать.Вот какой я ещё код нашёл https://myphpwiki.blogspot.com/2017/12/urls-filegetcontents.html.Но

Comment: @Cruze Fan ну вам тогда надо читать мануал, раздел о взаимодействии с файловой системой.